# Кто отлавливает переполнение буфера на стеке и кидает abort trap 6?

Tags: c

Собственно, сабж:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char str[16];

    if (argc < 2)
        return 1;

    sprintf(str, "Hello, %s!", argv[1]);


    return 0;
}
```

Вводим в качестве параметра командой строки слово, которое переполнит буфер, в этом случае просто должна происходить запись за пределами выделенной памяти. Программа не должна вылетать, так как это просто запись. В моем же случае (компилятор Clang) прога вылетает с abort trap.

Понятно что это ошибка времени выполнения, но откуда программа об этом узнала? Что такое abort trap 6 и кто его посылает?

Comment: А когда оно вылетает?

Comment: Пытаясь записать в массив `str` более 16 символов, функция `sprintf` пытается писать за пределами памяти, выделенной для массива `str`. Такая ситуация - неопределённое поведение - стандарт языка не налагает никаких требований на поведение программы в такой ситуации. В частности не гарантируется, что программа не должна вылетать. В этот раз программа вылетела, в следующий раз она может (теоретически :) ) отформатировать вам жёсткий диск.

Comment: *Во многих компиляторах имеется какой-либо род защиты стека. Определяемое на этапе исполнения значение, называемое „канарейкой“ (canary) пишется в конец стека рядом с адресом возврата. В конце каждой функции, это значение проверяется перед выполнением инструкции возврата. Если значение канарейки изменилось (по причине перезаписи в ходе переполнения), программа немедленно рухнет вместо продолжения.* — Хабрахабр, «[Как устроены дыры в безопасности: переполнение буфера](https://habrahabr.ru/post/266591/)»

Comment: [man signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) -- `SIGABRT       6       Core    Abort signal from abort(3)`, в общем, это делает компилятор, вставляя соответствующий код в свои проверки